# Dual boot - tried to mount Windows drive on Ubuntu 20, failed, now Windows won't boot

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, boot, grub

I installed Ubuntu on my laptop today in place of Mint. I was able to boot the Windows drive under Mint, but it failed in Ubuntu with the error described in [this page](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-do-you-repair-an-input-output-error-in-an-ntfs-partition/).

However, when I tried to start Windows to disable automatic startup, I got a BSoD with the stop code NTFS FILE SYSTEM. Trying to restart it again after a couple of times selecting Windows from the GRUB, it came to the 'Preparing Automatic Repair' screen which never went anywhere.

How to repair this? The laptop is a Lenovo, so it has a little hole that if triggered with a pin/paperclip etc boots into a menu that allows you to enter the BIOS, boot menu or 'System Recovery'. I tried the 'System Recovery' option, but it then reboots and hits the GRUB, and selecting Windows leads to the same old problem.

I like Linux and am happy with it for most things, but I need Windows to use Visual Studio and Word occasionally. If I have to reinstall Windows, I'd like to recover the files off the Windows partition first.

Comment: Not a solution.. but you could do what I (and many of my coworkers) now do.  Windows with WSL. all of Linux, all of Windows, No reboot. No GRUB. I write Linux c code in VS  and run and debug it on the same machine.  WSL IS NOT like Cygwin.  It is 100% the same distro ELF binaries you are installing on the other partition.

Comment: First, I would recommend booting with Ubuntu Live CD/USB. You should be able to access NTFS partitions if they're not broken. Then backup your files.

Comment: To your question, you should add what installer options you used to install Ubuntu, and what version. There are a number of possible issues, but in general you should install Windows first. Then in Windows create a 50+GB unallocated partition. Then in the Ubuntu installer, format that partition to ext4, then install Ubuntu there.